# Training Keras model with Dask Array is very slow

Tags: keras, dask, dask-delayed

I want to use `Dask` to read a large dataset and feed with it a `Keras` model. The data consists of audio files and I am using a custom function to read them. I have tried to apply `delayed` to this function and I collect all of the files in a dask array, as:

```
x = da.stack([da.from_delayed(delayed(get_item_data)(fp, sr, mono, post_processing, data_shape), shape=data_shape, dtype=np.float32) for fp in df['path']])
```

(See the [source](https://gist.github.com/thisisjl/1c59864ca09447a1ad77d1168f666f0c#file-data-py-L39-L49))

To train the Keras model, I compute X and Y as above and I input them to the function `fit`.

However, the training is very slow. I have tried to change the `chunksize`and it is still very slow.

Could you tell me if I am doing something wrong when creating the array? Or any good practices for it?

Thanks

Comment: Note that your link above isn't accessible.  Perhaps your github repository is private?

Comment: oh, yes, it is private. I have updated it with a gist. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know Keras doesn't have any built-in support for Dask.arrays.  So I'm not sure what will happen when you provide a dask.array directly to Keras functions.  My guess is that it will automatically convert the dask.array into a (possibly very large) numpy array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MRocklin, I thought Keras would support Dask.arrays because I saw [this thread](http://forums.fast.ai/t/managing-large-datasets-in-memory-and-on-disk/1412/19). Is there any workaround that you suggest?

Comment: You would probably have to feed keras with a sequence of numpy arrays.  Perhaps iterate and slice over your dask array in a for loop?  `for i in ...: model.train(..., {keras_x: x[i, ...]})`

Comment: One of the ways to try and improve performance would be to turn the shuffle argument of the fit/train command off/0 (or set it to 'batch') that way it only reads the array in linear blocks which should be faster (this is how the keras HDF5Matrix is setup to train more efficiently)